# Django middleware to 'do nothing' if certain criteria are met

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to create authentication middleware in python/django. Here is an example:

```
def middleware_function(request):
    if not user.is_admin:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        pass

def secure_view(request):
    user = request.usera
    middleware_function(request)

    print ("ok, you've passed security")
    return render(request, 'secure_view.html')
```

is the above a 'valid' way to do this? In that, it will re-direct if conditions aren't meant, but pass if things are ok?

Additionally, what would be the proper term for what I'm trying to create above? Would it be called 'middleware' or should be turned into a 'view decorator' ?

Comment: No, since the `return` will not return out of the view, and furthermore this is not really "middleware" (as how it is defined in Django).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem -- thanks for the response. How then would I 'return' the redirect if it's necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**: since the `return` in the `middleware_function` will *not* return something out of the view. It is simply the result of the `middleware_function`, and you decide not to do anything with it at all.

You furthermore can not use `user` here, since that is a *local* variable of `secure_view`, not a `global`, or `nonlocal` one (which would be bad design anyway).

Finally it is not middleware the way Django defines middleware. In Django middleware is a set of "pre-processing" and "post-processing" (and logging) for *all* the views. Here you only aim to "manipulate" a single view.

I would advice to implement a decorator, like:

```
from functools import wraps

def admin_required(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.user.is_admin:
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return redirect('login')
    return wrapped
```

and then you can add the decorator to your view:

```
@admin_required
def secure_view(request):
    print ("ok, you've passed security")
    return render(request, 'secure_view.html')
```

Djano however has already a decorator [**`user_passes_test`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser)
def secure_view(request):
    print ("ok, you've passed security")
    return render(request, 'secure_view.html')
```